# Group rows after applying user filter in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Is there any method in Power bi where I can apply the date filter first, and then group the rows based on a column to get aggregate data.

example Input data

[image]
When I select date range from 2017-10-24 to 2017-10-27,I need it to be like

[image]

Basically I need to filter data first with the date and then group it with respect to EmpId.

Comment: Are you trying to build a matrix visual or a data table or what?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to build a matrix visual, but data with percentage Pass/Fail data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **Slicer** for [Date] in your visualization.

[image]